# System.Threading.Timer don't want to import to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I try to define object from System.Threading.Timer but my Visual Studio 2017 (community) don't want to import this lib to my project, event I have installed packages and put `using System.Threading.Timer` manualy. Any one can help?

> See screen Shot below

[image]

Comment: If you could post the references, and using statements, do so. Links to images are not encouraged

Comment: you need to add the using to the .cs file class header.. and if necessary manually add it to the references node

Comment: You need `using System.Threading;`

Comment: As @JimMischel said, using System.Threading; should be used. Look at the example on msdn
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: unfortunetly it didn't helsp and even if I use only `using System.Threading` it crashes Task<> namespace. Now I have two kind of errors:
- `The type or namespace name 'Timer' could not be found`
- `The type or namespace name 'Task<>' could not be found`

IMO there is smth wrong with References

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a reference to a specific library. Simply add

```
using System.Threading;
```

at the top of the file. Create a timer like defined in the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.1